# What would stop me from creating a non pointer variable of my class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

**EDIT:: This seems to be a bug with Visual Studio 2013. I posted the answer below.**

For some reason beyond my comprehension, I can not create a non pointer variable of my class, **LineBuffer**. I have many classes throughout my code that use the same format but they work. I tried changing the name because I thought it may be possible that the class name was being used elsewhere but it still failed. Am I missing something simple? Is there a typo that I could not find in the last 2 hours of trying to fix this? This is literally giving me a headache. Any help here would be very much appreciated!

```
class TestClass
{
    LineBuffer lineBuffer;
    void LoadLine()
    {
        lineBuffer = LineBuffer();
    }
};
```

**The Errors I am getting are as follows:**

Error   3   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   E:\SoreTooth\Development\TestProjects\GraphicsDev-Test\Debug\GraphicsDev-Test.exe   1   1   GraphicsDev-Test

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall LineBuffer::~LineBuffer(void)" (__imp_??1LineBuffer@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0TestClass@@QAE@XZ$10 E:\SoreTooth\Development\TestProjects\GraphicsDev-Test\GraphicsDev-Test\main.obj    GraphicsDev-Test

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall LineBuffer::LineBuffer(void)" (__imp_??0LineBuffer@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall TestClass::TestClass(void)" (??0TestClass@@QAE@XZ)   E:\SoreTooth\Development\TestProjects\GraphicsDev-Test\GraphicsDev-Test\main.obj    GraphicsDev-Test

**The code for class LineBuffer.h:**

```
#ifndef _LineBuffer_
#define _LineBuffer_

#include "GraphicsManagement_API.h"

class GraphicsManagement_API LineBuffer
{
public:
    LineBuffer();
    ~LineBuffer();
};

#endif
```

**The code for LineBuffer.cpp:**

```
#include "LineBuffer.h"

LineBuffer::LineBuffer()
{

}

LineBuffer::~LineBuffer()
{

}
```

**And because I know you'll ask, the code for GraphicsManagement_API.h:**

```
#ifndef _GraphicsManagement_API_
#define _GraphicsManagement_API_

#include <d3d10.h>
#include <D3DX10.h>

#ifdef _GraphicsManagement_API_EXPORTS_
#define GraphicsManagement_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define GraphicsManagement_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif
#endif
```

**But this happens to work**

```
class TestClass
{
    LineBuffer * lineBuffer;
    void LoadLine()
    {
        lineBuffer = new LineBuffer();
    }
};
```

Comment: You have a linker error, not a compiler error.

Comment: Does it function properly with pointer? Because it seems like you are having include problems. Since compiler won't complain about pointer types, it's going to be compiled. Those link errors mean your constructor and destructor implementations are missing.

Comment: oops. Forgot to add the semicolons in the post. It would seem that i do have a linker error. But everything also seems to be in order.

Comment: maybe define `_GraphicsManagement_API_EXPORTS_` at the top of your `LineBuffer.cpp` file. the question is, have you just copied and modified this code, or have you designed it yourself?

Comment: I figured it out. It may be a Visual Studio bug. I'll answer my own question with details.

Comment: This is all code that I have designed myself. There is more code but I had it all commented out to narrow down the error to the posted content above. It seems to be a Visual Studio 2013 bug. I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you happen to come across this issue, recreate the files in question by deleting them and then creating a brand new file. In my case, when I created **LineBuffer.cpp**, I accidentally named it **LineBuffer.ccp** obviously this wont build and Visual Studio wont recognize it as a .**cpp** file. I figured I could just rename the file using the Visual Studio Solution Explorer. Apparently that does not work as one would expect. I had to delete the entire file and create a new file. Once I did this, it built successfully. I am not sure if this is a Visual Studio 2013 bug or if it is by design. Either way, this is the solution that worked for me.